# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, server

I took a game that my friend made and wanted to make it playable across browsers by sending keypress data between peers with WebRTC and websockets. However, I get this error in the console:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

My server file has the following few lines:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

const server = express();

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'lib')));
server.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
var users = {};
let usernames = [];


wss.on('connection', function(connection) {

   connection.on('message', function(message) {

      var data;
      try {
         data = JSON.parse(message);
      } catch (e) {
         console.log("Invalid JSON");
         data = {};
      }

      switch (data.type) {
         case "login":
            console.log("User logged", data.name);
            if(users[data.name]) {
               sendTo(connection, {
                  type: "login",
                  success: false
               });
            } else {
               users[data.name] = connection;
               connection.name = data.name;
               usernames.push(data.name);

               sendTo(connection, {
                  type: "login",
                  success: true,
                  users: usernames
               });
            }

            break;

         case "offer":
            console.log("Sending offer to: ", data.name);
            var conn = users[data.name];

            if(conn != null) {
               connection.otherName = data.name;

               sendTo(conn, {
                  type: "offer",
                  offer: data.offer,
                  name: connection.name
               });
            }

            break;

         case "answer":
            console.log("Sending answer to: ", data.name);
            var conn = users[data.name];

            if(conn != null) {
               connection.otherName = data.name;
               sendTo(conn, {
                  type: "answer",
                  answer: data.answer
               });
            }

            break;

         case "candidate":
            console.log("Sending candidate to:",data.name);
            var conn = users[data.name];

            if(conn != null) {
               sendTo(conn, {
                  type: "candidate",
                  candidate: data.candidate
               });
            }

            break;

         case "leave":
            console.log("Disconnecting from", data.name);
            var conn = users[data.name];
            conn.otherName = null;

            if(conn != null) {
               sendTo(conn, {
                  type: "leave"
               });
            }

            break;

         default:
            sendTo(connection, {
               type: "error",
               message: "Command not found: " + data.type
            });

            break;
      }
   });
```

And the client side of the connection looks as follows:

```
const Game = require("./game");
const GameView = require("./game_view");
var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
console.log('host: ', HOST);
console.log(process.env.PORT);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const connection = new WebSocket(HOST);

.....
```

This is the point that the error occurs and this is the caught error that I get:

```
bubbles
:
false
cancelBubble
:
false
cancelable
:
false
composed
:
false
currentTarget
:
WebSocket
defaultPrevented
:
false
eventPhase
:
0
isTrusted
:
true
path
:
Array(0)
returnValue
:
true
srcElement
:
WebSocket
target
:
WebSocket
timeStamp
:
213.01500000000001
type
:
"error"
__proto__
:
Event
```

I am not too familiar with server side programming and was trying to understand. I tried looking up this issue, but it seems like a variety of different things can cause this. If you want to see the repository you can see and try it yourself (uses webpack): [SlidingWarfare Repo](https://github.com/yashoss/slidingwarfarertc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The confusion starts here:

```
const server = express();
```

The `express` function doesn't really return a server, it returns an application. Commonly, the variable used for this is `app`, but that's of course nothing more than convention (i.e. not a requirement).

However, it becomes an issue when you pass the app to the WS server:

```
const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
```

That's because `SocketServer` requires an HTTP server instance, which `server` is not.

Here's a fix, without renaming your variables:

```
let httpServer = server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
...
const wss = new SocketServer({ server : httpServer });
```

(because when you call `.listen()` on the Express instance, it will return an HTTP server instance)

Using the variable naming convention it would be this:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'lib')));
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

let server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

const wss = new SocketServer({ server });
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that's how it worked and I'll definitely keep the naming conventions in mind as well.

Now that the keystroke are sending the canvas element messes up drawing after the "tanks" move.

You've been very helpful!

Comment: Dude I spent hours ripping my hair out on this one. This solved so many problems. I really appreciate this answer!