# There are always came out an error about the websocket when init a project by using reactjs or vuejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, vue.js, websocket

When I create a project by using create-react-app or vue init, and execute the command npm run dev/start, it always happened with an error about Websocket on my console tab. I don't understand what the problem is.
And the network tab always pending a request about socket constantly.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node/863/gwfp1dnj/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
// these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
devServer:{
  ...
  host: HOST || config.dev.host,
  port: PORT || config.dev.port,
  ...
}
```

Ensure your dev host and port is configured correctly that like above.

Comment: Thank you, but my project was created by react without a config file, I doubt if there is a global config existed in my system, cause it always got an error if I start a server on local.

Comment: [See the duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977916/websocket-connection-to-ws-localhost3000-failed-connection-closed-before) and hope it can help you @RandyOoorton

Comment: 老哥是中国的啊，感谢回答，但是我的项目是本地新建的，并没有做什么配置，在本地run的时候就会报这样的错误，我怀疑是我全局里面是不是之前配置过socket之类的监听啥的，因为不管我用vue还是react，都会有这样的错误，很纳闷，虽然不影响项目运行。